# Formula of regular 2m-gon inscribed in a unit cirlce

Tags: geometry

From pg 80 of Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I by R. Courant:

If we let$f_m$ denote the area of the regular $m$-gon inscribed in a unit circle, the area of the inscribed $2m$-gon is given by the formula:$$f_{2m}=\frac{m}{2}\sqrt{2-2 \sqrt{1-(2f_m/m)^2}}$$
Another formula is $f_m=\frac{m}{2}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{m}}$
The second formula is easy to derive but I have no idea how to derive the first one no matter how hard I try. I have tried to verify the first formula by first calculate for example the area for $m=10$ polygon using the second formula then the first formula by $m=5$. It is correct for $m\ge4$ but when I try to calculate for the case $m=3$, I get $1.5$ from the first formula instead of the correct $2.598$(that is the area of regular hexagon inscribed in a unit circle). Can someone please guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the rule of the sum:
$$
\cos(2\alpha) = \cos^2 \alpha - \sin^2 \alpha = 1-2\sin^2(\alpha)
$$
hence the bisection formula
$$
\sin(\alpha) = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2\alpha)}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\alpha)}}{2}}
$$

Now replace $f_m = \frac m 2 \sin \frac{2\pi}{m}$...